# Fiber Warning in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-three-fiber

Without any changes to my react-native app, I am suddenly getting this warning:

```
 WARN  Could not find Fiber with id "21847"
```

What is this about and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen.  Let me ask, are you running Flipper?  As soon as I killed Flipper the problem stopped immediately.

Comment: Yes I noticed that too. The issue is happening when using Flipper on iOS simulator. However it is really inconvenient to kill flipper every time. Could you find any solutions for this?

Comment: I have not.  I can't get used to flipper.  I rarely use it, so I was just glad to find out it wasn't a problem with my app. The state of tooling for react-native isn't that great right now...  I was getting the error when I was running on an Android device, so I think whatever the issue is is a little higher up the chain and specific to how it listens to React.